# $x \otimes S \cong y \otimes S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a $R$-module. Which conditions could one find for elements $x,y \in M$, so that the isomorphism
$$ x \otimes  S \cong y \otimes S $$
as $R$-modules is true? $S$ denotes a submodule of $M$.

Regards

Comment: "abelian ring"? What do you mean by $x\otimes S$?

Comment: The ring should be commutative and $x \otimes S$ is the tensorproduct.

Comment: @user58257: did you mean $xR\otimes S$ ? Is the isomorphism supposed to be true for any submodule $S$ of $M$ ?